# Save samples that repeat every 300 ms

Tags: matlab, loops, save, frame, milliseconds

I want to sample an audio signal. I have a `wav` file 5 seconds long. I want save samples every 300 ms.

I use function `audioread` in MATLAB that read samples containing in file, this is my code:

```
[signal,fs]=audioread('file.wav');

dt = 1/fs;
N = length(signal);
t = 0:dt:(N-1)*dt;

plot(t,signal)
ms=t*1000;
```

How can I do save in an array samples that are repeated every 300 ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your `wav` file has a sampling rate of `fs = 44100` (which is quite common), i.e. you have `44100` samples per second. Now, you want to have one sample each `0.3 s`. You have to calculate the corresponding number of samples to "skip" with respect to your original sampling rate, i.e. `skip = 0.3 * fs = 13230` in this case. Now, you can simply access each `skip`'th element in your original `signal` (and also time interval `t`).

Here's some code to do the work, and visualize the above:

```matlab
% Artificial data
signal = sin(linspace(0, 2*pi, 5 * 44100));
fs = 44100;
dt = 1 / fs;
N = length(signal); 
t = 0:dt:(N-1)*dt; 

% "Re-sampling" parameters
dt_new = 0.3; 
skip = dt_new * fs;

% Extract every skip'th value from original time interval and signal
t_new = t(1:skip:end).'
signal_new = signal(1:skip:end);

% Some visualization
figure(1);
hold on;
plot(t, signal);
plot(t_new, signal_new, 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 15);
hold off;
```

We get the following output, the original signal is blue, the red points are the samples at every `0.3 s`:

[image: Output]

If you have a look at `t_new`, you see, that the sampling points exactly match your desired interval of `0.3 s`:

```
t_new =
     0.00000
     0.30000
     0.60000
     0.90000
     1.20000
     1.50000
     1.80000
     2.10000
     2.40000
     2.70000
     3.00000
     3.30000
     3.60000
     3.90000
     4.20000
     4.50000
     4.80000
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** There's also a [`resample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) function available in the *Signal Processing Toolbox*. I'm not sure, if this function is useful here, since the new sampling rate would be `fs_new = 1 / 0.3 = 3.3333`, but `resample` only accepts integers. Maybe, there's another more sophisticated (toolbox) function to do the job automatically.